# Weakest topology on curves of $R^2$ that makes length a continuous function

Tags: gt.geometric-topology

We know that the length of curves is not semi-continuous for certain topologies, and is for some others. A natural question I asked myself recently is "what do we *need* to make length continuous", i.e.: what is the weakest topology on curves of, let's say $\mathbb R^2$, that makes arclength a continuous function ? Can we describe it with tools and other topologies that are already known ?

I understand that even the sole notion of "topology on curves" is already intricate and that this topology will not be separated: any two curves with the same length, even different and far away one from another, will be in every neighborhood of the other.

So I guess that we have to reduce the problem by looking at only a subclass of parametrizations (with $\gamma(0)=0$ for instance and that is not enough because a same curve can be parametrized with different speeds), but this changes the way the problem is posed and is a tough question itself. For instance here the seminorm of $W^{1,1}$ is enough but certainly not necessary !).

Anyway, I just want to see if we can describe "the minimum requirements" to make length continuous, in one way or another, and I don't see anything on that precise question in the litterature ! Also, maybe this "weakest topology such that" question is not the correct way to see want I want to see.

Comment: Why don't you take some coarse topology that still distinguishes curves that are geometrically far away, but for which $L$ is still not continuous (say $C^0$ or even $L^2$), and look for the coarsest topology that is finer than the given one and has $L$ continuous? It would be interesting to see if starting from $C^0$ and from $L^2$, you get the same answer. Or forget parametrisations, and work with Hausdorff distance?

Comment: Do really want to consider the parameterization as part of the curve "data"or are you just interested in the curve as a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.  If the latter, then the weakest topology that is actually studied would be the weak* convergence as measures.  I.e. $\gamma_i\to \gamma$ if and only if $\int_{\gamma_i} \phi d\mathcal{H}^1 \to \int_{\gamma} \phi d\mathcal{H}^1$ for all compactly supported continuous functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Here $d\mathcal{H}^1$ is just integration with respect to Hausdorff measure (i.e. the induced length element if you prefer).

Comment: The answer that you surely did not want to hear is: Let $X$ be this space of curves, e.g. $X=\{c:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^2\,|\,c\text{ continuous}\} / \approx$ where $\approx$ describes the equivalence of different parametrisations of the same curve, and let $L:X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be the arclength-function. Then the weakest topology on $X$ that makes $L$ continuous is what one calls the initial topology on $X$ induced by $L$, its open sets are the arbitrary unions of sets of the form $L^{-1}(O)$, with $O\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ open.

Comment: Matthias > of course, but what I wanted to know is whether this precise topology can be described by some other topologies or by tools we already know.

Sebastian > oh, sure, good idea. I'll have a look into that.

Foliations > thanks ! Can you explain why and the additional conditions you put (because this topology is separated)